# How to add rows with a DataGrid and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF MVVM app that contains an editable DataGrid. I am subscribing the DG SelectedItem event to a property in my ViewModel. This works well for modifying existing records and saving the changes to the database.

However, how can I tell when a new row is being created? When I click on the new row in the DG, the SelectedItem event does not fire. After the new row is created and I click on an exisitng row, the SelectedItem event fires but the EntityState does NOT know a row was added.
How can I add a new row to my DB within the DG? Or, is there a better way to accomplish this?

This is what I am currently doing:

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ContactList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemContact,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          .....>
```

ViewModel:

```
public Contact SelectedItemContact
{
    get { return _selectedItemContact; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _selectedItemContact)
        {
                bool changesMade = Repository.Context.
                ObjectStateManager.
                GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added |
                EntityState.Deleted |
                EntityState.Modified
                ).Any();
            if (changesMade)
            {
                Repository.Context.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Changes Saved!");
            }
                _selectedItemContact = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItemContact");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be considered a duplicate of this:
[WPF DataGrid - Event for New Rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617810/wpf-datagrid-event-for-new-rows)

See if that helps you at all.

Comment: This should have been a comment.