# How to Add a New Row to DataGrid in MVVM Friendly Way

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have the following `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResource, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources, Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                IsAsync=True}"> ... </<DataGrid>
```

I am using the MVVM pattern to bind to an `ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel> Resources` and this works great. I have a button that adds a new row and this is done by adding a new `ResourceViewModel` to the `Resources` collection - great. Now, I want the user to be able to click on the empty last row, and this automatically creates a new record in the `DataGrid`.

I have made sure the `DataGrid` has `CanUserAddRows=True`. I have made sure the class in the collection `Resources` (`ResourceViewModel`) that I am binding to has a default constructor (no parameters) and I have made sure the collection type is not readonly. When the user clicks on the last row the default constructor fires but to correctly instantiate the new `ResourceViewModel` object in need a reference to either the grid of the `Resources` collection...

I suppose I could use and `AttachedCommand` on the `CellBeginEdit` event and then add a new `ResourceViewModel` to the observable collection there, **is there a standard way of doing this?**

---

Note, I have read the following questions and these are of no help to me

1. [WPF DataGrid - Event for New Rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617810/wpf-datagrid-event-for-new-rows)
2. [How to add rows with a DataGrid and MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556809/how-to-add-rows-with-a-datagrid-and-mvvm)

---

Edit. It turns out that I am having problems doing this due to a bug in the WPF `DataGrid`. See [Nigel Spencer's Blog](http://blog.spencen.com/2009/04/30/problems-binding-to-selectedvalue-with-microsoftrsquos-wpf-datagrid.aspx?view=threaded#Comment). However, his fix is not working for me at the moment...

Comment: The updated link to Nigel Spencer's blog post is [Problems binding to SelectedValue with WPF DataGrid](http://blogs.spencen.com/?p=611)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you know how to correctly add new items into your data bound collection to result in a new item being added to the `DataGrid` and your question actually relates to how can you do this when the user clicks on the last row in the `DataGrid`. The general way to handle some event in the view model is to create an `Attached Property` (if one does not already exist) that handles that event for you.

For instance, you could create an `Attached Property` that attaches a handler to the relevant event and another of type `ICommand` which you could execute when the event handler is called. Then you could write the functionality of that `ICommand` in your view model (in which you add a new item to your data bound collection) and data bind your `ICommand` implementation to the `Attached ICommand Property`.

As I'm fairly sure you know how to define `Attached Property`s, I won't insult you by showing you. Please let me know if I have misunderstood you, or not made myself clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I set an attached command to fire on the `InitializingNewItem` event. This fires when I put the last row of the `DataGrid` in edit mode and before the grid attempts to create the new item. Here I can add the new item, but the `DataGrid` goes on to try an instantiate the items itself using the default constructor. I wan't to be able to stop the grid from automatically doing this as I can use the command and the event to do what I want...

Comment: So I suppose the question becomes, what is the best way to do this; A. Cancel the event after I add the new row (how, I have no idea). B. Let the grid do this itself - but then how to get the object correctly initialised in the default ctor? Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: I very rarely use these controls, so unfortunately, I'm not really in a position to be able to give advanced advise about them. Good luck with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attached property that registers a command for adding rows (assuming the source collection contains a generic type argument):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RegisterAddCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RegisterAddCommand", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnRegisterAddCommandChanged));
public static bool GetRegisterAddCommand(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (bool)obj.GetValue(RegisterAddCommandProperty);
}
public static void SetRegisterAddCommand(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
{
    obj.SetValue(RegisterAddCommandProperty, value);
}
static void OnRegisterAddCommandChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is DataGrid)
    {
        var DataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            DataGrid.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(AddCommand, AddCommand_Executed, AddCommand_CanExecute));
    }
}

public static readonly RoutedUICommand AddCommand = new RoutedUICommand("AddCommand", "AddCommand", typeof(DataGridExtensions));
static void AddCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var DataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

    var ItemsSourceType = DataGrid.ItemsSource.GetType();
    var ItemType = ItemsSourceType.GetGenericArguments().Single();

    DataGrid.Items.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(ItemType));
}
static void AddCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = (sender as DataGrid).CanUserAddRows;
}
```

And then you can apply the command to a button somewhere like this:

```
<Button Command="{x:Static Extensions:DataGridExtensions.AddCommand}"/>
```

Don't forget to specify the command target.